# Read aloud not working on password protected document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

Our school wants to use Word to create digital tests. In order to do this, the teachers create a word document, add questions and form/text fields, and then password protect the document. This way, the students can only fill in the form/text fields, but cannot change the layout or questions.

Some of our students need the 'read aloud' functionality. We've noticed that, once we password protect the document, only the fillable form/text fields can be read, but not the questions.

Is it possible to activate the 'read aloud' functionality on a password protected document for the protected parts?

[Here you can find an example document.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AowYKSpO9ciHP3mlmrP2a9FB4KCbUmCU/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117186462075380628683&rtpof=true&sd=true) Open it and start the Immersive Reader. The reader cannot read the exercises.

Comment: Which version of Office are you using?

Comment: Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20188) 64-bit

Comment: Could you post online an example document (on Dropbox, OneDrive etc) ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AowYKSpO9ciHP3mlmrP2a9FB4KCbUmCU/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117186462075380628683&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Open the document and start the Immersive Reader from the View tab. The reader is not able to read the questions or other texts.

Comment: I'm on Microsoft 365. In my case it reads the whole document aloud, but the text jumps around like crazy. In my opinion this feature is quite unusable.

Comment: Yes, you can't use the online 365 version, because you won't be able to fill in the fields. You need the standalone app.

Comment: I'm using the desktop version, but the Read Aloud feature is behaving very badly.